# Regex to find Shorturl in a twitter text file

Tags: java, regex

I need to find short url in the text post in java. I have the following regex expression 
"(http://(bit\.ly|t\.co|lnkd\.in|tcrn\.ch).*?)\s"

I have 2 questions

1. The problem with the above expression is it doesn't match the short
   url if it is at the end of line.  ex  For text    "blah
   http://linkd.in/R9Msf3 blah"  gives "http://linkd.in/R9Msf3 "

   But blah blah http://linkd.in/R9Msf3 does not gives
   "http://linkd.in/R9Msf3"

   Any suggestions how to match both patterns ? Basically I just need
   to replace the short url out of the text.
2. Also is there a better way to get all the short url format? If I
   hard code it then everytime I would have to add a new format to the
   config.

Comment: Are you only going to get shortUrls or is it possible you'll get normal urls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.*` use `\S*` to avoid matching whitespace. You don't need the `?` and you can use `\b` instead of `\s` to match the boundary between the end of the url and whitespace or end of string.

```
(http://(bit\.ly|t\.co|lnkd\.in|tcrn\.ch)\S*)\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `(\s|$)` at the end of your REGEX

so
`http://(linkd\.in|t\.co|bitly\.co|tcrn\.ch).*?(\s|$)`

Tested with [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com)

[image]